# Java related that includes using constructor and classes

Tags: java

I am self studying for AP computer science and I am having a little bit of trouble with this question.

1. An organization raises money by selling boxes of cookies. A cookie order specifies the variety of cookie and the number of boxes ordered. The declaration of the CookieOrder class is shown below.

   ```
   public class CookieOrder
   {
   /**
   Constructs a new
   CookieOrder
   object.
   */
   public CookieOrder(String variety, int numBoxes)
   { /*
   implementation not shown
   */ }
   /** @return
   the variety of cookie being ordered
   */
   public String getVariety()
   { /*
   implementation not shown
   */ }
   /** @return
   the number of boxes being ordered
   */
   public int getNumBoxes()
   { /*
   implementation not shown
   */ }
   // There may be instance variables, constr uctors, and methods that are not shown.
   }
   ```

The MasterOrder class maintains a list of the cookies to be purchased. The declaration of the MasterOrder class is shown below.

```
public class MasterOrder
{
/**
The list of all cookie orders
*/
private List<CookieOrder> orders;
/**
Constructs a new
MasterOrder
object.
*/
public MasterOrder()
{ orders = new ArrayList<CookieOrder>(); }
/**
Adds
theOrder
to the master order.
* @param theOrder
the cookie order to add to the master order
*/
public void addOrder(CookieOrder theOrder)
{ orders.add(theOrder); }
/** @return
the sum of the number of boxes of all of the cookie orders
*/
public int getTotalBoxes()
{ /*
to be implemented in part (a)
*/ }
/**
Removes all cookie orders from the master
order that have the same variety of
*
cookie as
cookieVar
and returns the total number of
boxes that were removed.
* @param cookieVar
the variety of cookies to remove from the master order
* @return
the total number of boxes of
cookieVar
in the cookie orders removed
*/
public int removeVariety(String cookieVar)
{ /*
to be implemented in part (b)
*/ }
//
There may be instance variables, constr
uctors, and methods that are not shown.
}
```

(a) The getTotalBoxes method computes and returns the sum of the number of boxes of all cookie orders. If there are no cookie orders in the master order, the method returns 0. Complete method getTotalBoxes below.

```
/** @return
the sum of the number of boxes of all of the cookie orders
*/
public int getTotalBoxes() 

According to college board the answer is:

int sum = 0;

for (CookieOrder a: this.orders)
    sum += a.getNumBoxes();

return sum;
```

Here are my questions:

1. How is "CookieOrder" a type?
2. If I did print out 'a', what would be printed out?
3. Why is the keyword "this" needed?

I would prefer a brain-friendly answer.

Comment: The first class makes a CookieOrder object, and you can have lists of objects.

Comment: It would be important to know what language you come from. Java has concepts of classes acting as typrs, with inheritance, assignment, and function calls available upon it.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How is "CookieOrder" a type?

It's a type because it is [defined in a class declaration.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html)

> 2. If I did print out 'a', what would be printed out?

Why is this a hypothetical? Run the code and see.

> 3.Why is the keyword "this" needed?

It's not needed *in this case.* However, some might argue that it improves code style / maintenance / readability / whatever in this case.

Comment: I am completely new in this field as you probably can already tell. Now I have a question about the "CookieOrder" type. What type of Data can be stored in that type? & I can't run the code cause it is not completed. But what I was trying to figure out is that would the "order" arraylist contain the variety or the number of boxes?

Comment: Neither. The `order` list contains `CookieOrder` instances.

Comment: Why is it there then?

Comment: Do you understand [Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) at all? The declaration `List<CookieOrder>` means "list of `CookieOrder`." It's there to hold all of the line items of the master order.

Comment: @MdChowdhury - CookieOrder is a class,  So far it has no instance variables defined and hence its instances store nothing.  The `orders` ArrayList would contain instances of the CookieOrder class.

Comment: Let me explain it to you. int,double etc. are primitive data types. They can hold values where Strings and classes are object types. Strings can hold words and stuff. My question is what would this CookieOrder class type be able to hold?

Comment: Anything you put in it:  write `private int foo` in the `CookieOrder` class and now a `CookieOrder` holds an integer.  Think of a class as a container for other variables.  (But right now, your class has no variables so it doesn't hold any data.)

Comment: @Wyzard Now I understand. Finally someone expert in StackOverflow. Btw what would the order arraylist hold? A number or a variety?

Comment: A `List<CookieOrder>` holds a list of `CookieOrder` objects.  You can create `CookieOrder` objects (e.g. with `new CookieOrder(...)`) and add them to the list using its `add` method.

Comment: @MdChowdhury - You need to understand that StackOverflow does not exist to teach basic programming.  It is intended for people who already know at least the basics and have specific questions.  To learn basic programming you should take a class or find a good instructional book -- one that you can comprehend.

Comment: @MdChowdhury see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html for an example class

Comment: @HotLicks Thats not true. StackOverflow is made for people like us :)

Comment: BTW:  "Finally someone expert in StackOverflow" — you're insulting everyone else on the site because they didn't teach basic Java to you.  There are lots of experts here, but many of them don't bother with basic questions that'd be answered by an introductory programming textbook.

Comment: BTW MR @Wyzard thats why people say things like this about this site http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow

Comment: From the standpoint of someone who browses SO looking for interesting questions to either answer (and actually have to use my head) or learn from (other people's answers), the biggest problem here is the low signal-to-noise ratio.  People get a compile error and come straight to SO without doing any basic research on what the error message means.  I cast more close votes (on unclear/offtopic/downright-bad questions) than upvotes (on clear, interesting, good questions).

Comment: @Wyzard  Please go check my most recent question then.  It's as clear as I can make it so far,.. interesting, and I need help :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416475/preserving-line-breaks-when-updating-and-reading-from-oracle-db-blob

Comment: @MdChowdhury - You obviously didn't read that site you linked: Much of the criticism of SO there was directed at *you* and those like you who seek instant gratification rather than trying to do their own homework.